# suppose $S$ is a LI subset of a vector space $V$ and $u$ is a vector in $V$ with $u$ not in $Span(S)$. Show $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n,u\}$ is LI

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

suppose $S=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ is a linearly independent subset of a vector space $V$ and $u$ is a vector in $V$ with $u$ not in $\operatorname{Span}(S)$. Show $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n,u\}$ is linearly independent.

I'm stuck on this proof and having trouble finding a way to move on. I started by writing let $W=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n,u\}$. Then if $W$ is LI,

$k_1v_1 + k_2v_2 +...+k_nv_n + k_0u = 0$ vector must have all $k$'s $= 0$.

since $S=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ is LI I know all the $k$'s but $k_0 = 0$... but how can I show $k_0 = 0$ maybe?

If I can't do that I'm having trouble finding out how these clues lead to the fact that W is LI...

if $u$ not in $\operatorname{Span}(S)$ tells me something I'm not sure how it relates to this result...

Comment: wait, since u is not in span(S), it can't be written as a linear combo of v1,v2,..vn .. so that proves k0 = 0.... is that right?

Comment: if thats it, i'm having trouble showing that

Comment: wait... i can take the span(W) = 0 vector, plug in 0s for v1....vn, then solve for k0, giving me k0 = 0..... QED. that should work right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be a linearly independent set and $u \notin span(S)$.  By way of contradiction, suppose $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,u\}$ is a linearly dependent set.  Then there exist constants $c_1,\ldots,c_n,c$, not all zero, such that $c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n+cu=0$.  Consider two possible cases.  If $c=0$, then we have found constants $c_1,\ldots,c_n$, not all zero, such that $c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n=0$. This implies that the $v_i$'s are linearly dependent, a contradiction.  If $c \ne 0$, then some $c_i$ is also not equal to 0, and by bringing the term $cu$ to the other side of the equality and dividing the equation by $c$, we are able to express $u$ as a linear combination of the $v_i$'s. This contradicts the fact that $u \notin span(S)$.  Thus, the set $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,u\}$ is a linearly independent set.